# Specify Multiple Match "Lengths" with Regex Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm new to regex and not sure how exactly to ask this question, but I'll do my best.

Here is a simple expression I'm working with:

```
"^[0-9]{13}$"
```

This matches a string of numbers exactly 13 characters long. According to the Python documentation I can set a range like this that would match a string of numbers anywhere between 13 and 20 characters long, for example:

```
"^[0-9]{13,20}$"
```

My question is, how can I exclude certain "lengths" from a range? For example:

```
"^[0-9]{13,20 EXCEPT for 15 or 17}$"
```

In that example I want to include any length between 13 and 20 EXCEPT for 15 and 17.

Is this possible?

I've looked in the Python 3 regex documentation and I can't personally find a way to do this, but I'm also not experienced with it yet so I could be overlooking something.

Comment: No, it's not possible.  Just go through the matches afterward and reject the ones that are the wrong length.  The regex will have done the hard job already.

Comment: `^(?!.{15}$)(?!.{17}$)[0-9]{13,20}$` - the two negative lookaheads reject any string that's one of the prohibited lengths.  Not saying that this is a good way to implement your requirement, just that it's *possible*.

Comment: `^[0-9]{13}([0-9]([0-9][0-9]([0-9][0-9]{1,3})?)?)?$`, but jason's regex is more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd pattern, you can replace the start of string `^` by a *custom/restricted* one `^(?!(.{15}|.{17})$)` (that is built based on the lengths to exclude). This will make sure to match every start of string but only if the length of this one is not 15 or 17 characters.

> ```
> Use ^(?!(.{15}|.{17})$)[0-9]{13,20}$ instead of ^[0-9]{13,20}$
> ```

And here is a generic code to handle different discontinous ranges :

```
# feel free to adjust the values
(l, r), excep = [13, 20], [15, 17]

to_excl = "|".join(".{%s}" % n for n in excep)

pat = re.compile(r"^(?!(%s)$)[0-9]{%s,%s}$" % (to_excl, l, r))
```

Test/Output :

```
for t in text:
    print(
        f"{t:<22}", f"{len(t):<4}",
        "match" if pat.match(t) else "no-match"
    )
    
01234                  5    no-match
012345678901234        15   no-match
0123456789012345       16   match
01234567890123456      17   no-match
012345678901234567     18   match
012345678901234567890  21   no-match
```

Used input :

```
from string import digits
s = digits; lens = [5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21]
text = [s * (l // 10) + s[:l % 10] for l in lens]
   
['01234',
 '012345678901234',
 '0123456789012345',
 '01234567890123456',
 '012345678901234567',
 '012345678901234567890']
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your help and insight!

Answer (score 0):

Well... yes, you can, but that would require more than just one quantifier.

[With alternatives](https://regex101.com/r/NFe5NW/1):

```
^
(?:
  [0-9]{13,14}   # 13 or 14
|
  [0-9]{16}      # or 16
|
  [0-9]{18,20}   # or 18, 19, 20.
)
$
```

[With lookaheads](https://regex101.com/r/NFe5NW/2):

```
^
(?!.{15}$)(?!.{17}$)    # Assure that the length is neither 15 nor 17,
[0-9]{13,20}            # and at the same time, 13 <= length <= 20.
$
```

[With lookbehinds](https://regex101.com/r/NFe5NW/3):

```
^
[0-9]{13,20}            # Basically the same pattern,
(?<!^.{15})(?<!^.{17})  # just inverted.
$
```

With normal Python code:

```py
# Note the lack of anchors and the use of .fullmatch()
# That method is used here since it is more readable,
# and it automatically adds anchors.

_13_to_20_digits = re.compile('[0-9]{13,20}')

if _13_to_20_digits.fullmatch(text) and len(text) not in (15, 17):
  frobnicate()
```

Choose one. Whichever you prefer. Personally I like the last, since it is crystal clear, even to those who don't know regex.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>